# How do I replace boxed trait objects of Any with an enum while keeping the same API?

Tags: rust

I currently use the following pattern for storing multiple different user-defined types in a container.

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Container {
    inner: HashMap<TypeId, Box<Any>>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn insert<T: Any>(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.inner.insert(TypeId::of::<T>(), Box::new(data));
    }
    pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<T>())
            .and_then(|a| a.downcast_ref::<T>())
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to move away from using boxed trait objects to using enums in their place (type parameter `G`), but by keeping the same outward-facing API. The goal here is to get around virtualization by using an enum that encapsulates every known user-supplied type `T`:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Container<G> {
    inner: HashMap<TypeId, G>,
}

impl<G> Default for Container<G> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Container {
            inner: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl<G> Container<G> {
    pub fn insert<T: Any + Into<G>>(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.inner.insert(TypeId::of::<T>(), data.into());
    }
    pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeA(u32);

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeB(String);

    /// This is the enum that should replace boxed `Any` trait objects. Users also need to supply
    /// this enum. Maybe they'll need to implement additional traits to get `borrow` to work.
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    enum Group {
        A(TypeA),
        B(TypeB),
    }

    impl From<TypeA> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeA) -> Self {
            Group::A(value)
        }
    }

    impl From<TypeB> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeB) -> Self {
            Group::B(value)
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn insert() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        assert_eq!(
            c.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<TypeA>()),
            Some(&Group::A(data.clone()))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn borrow() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        let borrowed = c.borrow::<TypeA>();
        assert_eq!(borrowed, Some(&data));
    }
}
```

How would I go about implementing the `borrow` method? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I realized that I run in to another problem when trying to implement a `remove` method for my container that should return ownership of the supplied data back to the user. Based on the title of my question, this still falls under the same issue. May I update my question or should I post a new one?

Comment: This is a tricky situation. You generally don't want to rewrite questions to invalidate answers, but you are the only answerer. In this case, I'd ask myself if the question *title* would need to change. If it would to still make sense, I'd ask a new question with the new title. This question can be linked to in a new question, but it also stands alone for future people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just downcast from the enum that implements `GroupTrait` using the method `downcast_ref` on `Any`:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait GroupTrait {
    fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T>;
}

struct Container<G> {
    inner: HashMap<TypeId, G>,
}

impl<G> Default for Container<G>
where
    G: GroupTrait,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Container {
            inner: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl<G> Container<G>
where
    G: GroupTrait,
{
    pub fn insert<T: Any + Into<G>>(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.inner.insert(TypeId::of::<T>(), data.into());
    }
    pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<T>()).and_then(|g| g.borrow())
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeA(u32);

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeB(String);

    /// This is the enum that should replace boxed `Any` trait objects. Users also need to supply
    /// this enum. Maybe they'll need to implement additional traits to get `borrow` to work.
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    enum Group {
        A(TypeA),
        B(TypeB),
    }

    impl From<TypeA> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeA) -> Self {
            Group::A(value)
        }
    }

    impl From<TypeB> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeB) -> Self {
            Group::B(value)
        }
    }

    impl GroupTrait for Group {
        fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
            use self::Group::*;
            match *self {
                A(ref i) => Any::downcast_ref(i),
                B(ref i) => Any::downcast_ref(i),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn insert() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        assert_eq!(
            c.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<TypeA>()),
            Some(&Group::A(data.clone()))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn borrow() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        let borrowed = c.borrow::<TypeA>();
        assert_eq!(borrowed, Some(&data));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Any::is::<T>(i)` is stable and happens to be shorter anyway.

Comment: In fact, you can just use `A(ref i) => Any::downcast_ref(i)` and get rid of the conditional and the unsafe.

Comment: I was unaware that supplying your own `self` argument was legal in rust. Great, and it even works for mutable borrows. Thanks!

Comment: methods are mostly just syntax sugar for passing `self` implicitly.