# How do I extend an enum-based multi-type container with a remove method?

Tags: rust

This question is based on information given in [another recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457323). I would like to extend the following `Container` with a `remove` method that returns ownership of the stored data to the caller. The accompanying unit test should explain its desired behaviour.

In the previous case (see referenced question), I would have used the `downcast` method on the `Box<Any>` object, but I don't know how to approach the problem in the case where enums are used instead. I'm grateful for pointers.

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait GroupTrait {
    fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T>;
}

struct Container<G> {
    inner: HashMap<TypeId, G>,
}

impl<G> Default for Container<G>
where
    G: GroupTrait,
{
    fn default() -> Self {
        Container {
            inner: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl<G> Container<G>
where
    G: GroupTrait,
{
    pub fn insert<T: Any + Into<G>>(&mut self, data: T) {
        self.inner.insert(TypeId::of::<T>(), data.into());
    }
    pub fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<T>()).and_then(|g| g.borrow())
    }
    pub fn remove<T: Any>(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeA(u32);

    /// This should be an user-defined type that implements the Any trait.
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
    struct TypeB(String);

    /// This is the enum that should replace boxed `Any` trait objects. Users also need to supply
    /// this enum. Maybe they'll need to implement additional traits to get `borrow` to work.
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    enum Group {
        A(TypeA),
        B(TypeB),
    }

    impl From<TypeA> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeA) -> Self {
            Group::A(value)
        }
    }

    impl From<TypeB> for Group {
        fn from(value: TypeB) -> Self {
            Group::B(value)
        }
    }

    impl GroupTrait for Group {
        fn borrow<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
            use self::Group::*;
            match *self {
                A(ref i) => Any::downcast_ref(i),
                B(ref i) => Any::downcast_ref(i),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn insert() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        assert_eq!(
            c.inner.get(&TypeId::of::<TypeA>()),
            Some(&Group::A(data.clone()))
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn borrow() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        let borrowed = c.borrow::<TypeA>();
        assert_eq!(borrowed, Some(&data));
    }

    #[test]
    fn remove() {
        let mut c: Container<Group> = Default::default();
        let data = TypeA(100);
        c.insert(data.clone());
        assert_eq!(c.remove::<TypeA>(), Some(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: `HashMap::remove` could work as long as it's possible to unwrap the resulting `Option<Group>` into an `Option<TypeA>`. I would probably try something with `TryInto` or `TryFrom`. Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, `TryFrom` is possible. However, I'd go with `Into<Option<T>>`:

```
pub fn remove<T: Any>(&mut self) -> Option<T>
where
    G: Into<Option<T>>,
{
    self.inner.remove(&TypeId::of::<T>()).and_then(|g| g.into())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0c72269bc5e038638d286e354c570c62&version=nightly)

I'd choose  `Into<Option<T>>` over `TryInto<T>` because `Into<Option<T>>` results in an `Option` while `TryInto<T>` results in `Result<T, Self::Error>`